# How to debug UIWebView with Safari using Xcode7/iOS9?

Tags: ios, safari, uiwebview

Today I had to upgrade to `Xcode7`/`iOS9` and I cannot debug my `UIWebView` using `Safari` anymore.

I'm still on `OSX 10.10`. I've searched for some info about it, but found none.
I've already updated `Safari` to `9.0`, but no use.

Is there anything special I need to do in order to have my app listed under `Develop` menu in `Safari`? It used to work with `iOS 8.4` and `Xcode 6.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of not keeping the question unaswered...
It was a stupid issue actually. The develop menu didn't appear after the upgrade. I had to restart the system to make it work.
Sounds like something obvious, but I never restart my system [uptime of several months is a usual for me].